# wpa_cli lost connection to wpa_supplicant after starting armon-ng

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, wpa-supplicant

On Kali Linux I have `wpa_supplicant` and `wpa_cli` running on `wlan0`. When I run

> $ airmon-ng start wlan0

`wlan0mon` interface being created in place of `wlan0`, and `wpa_cli` shows

> Connection to wpa_supplicant lost - trying to reconnect

Restarting `wpa_cli` causes

> Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying message

Can I, in principle, use `wpa_cli` with interface in **monitor mode**?

In general, I need to set interface to p2p_listen state (with `wpa_cli`), and watch P2P probe requests and responses in Wireshark (that's why I should set `wlan0` to monitor mode).

Comment: Please add the contents of wpa-supplicant conf file

Comment: Three is no conf. wpa_supplicant runs with these parameters:
`/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant`
In /etc/wpa_supplicant/ there are only action_wpa.sh, functions.sh   and ifupdown.sh